# How do I merge two vectors of same length into one vector that has the same length as well in R

Tags: r, vector, merge

I have two vectors like this:

```
vec1<-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
vec2<-c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

I want to merge it somehow to turn it into this:

```
vec<-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
pmax(vec1, vec2)
[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

or with `|`

```
+(vec1|vec2)
```

Comment: Is there any restriction on how many vectors I can use pmax on? For example, can I use `pmax` on 100 vectors in one function?

Comment: @msening you can use any number of vectors as it is a variadic argument (`...`), thus you may do `pmax(vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4, ..., vec100, na.rm = TRUE)` or create a list and use `do.call` with `pmax` i.e. `do.call(pmax, mget(paste0('vec', 1:100)))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(vec1==0 & vec2==0, 0, 1)

[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
```